# How to set the domain name for tornado

Tags: python, web, server, tornado

I'm using tornado to build a web server. Now everything's ready, I can visit my website with the IP address of my server.

Also, I've got a domain name but I don't know how to use the domain name to visit my server.

For example, the IP is `a.a.a.a` and the domain name is `www.mysite.com`. For now I can use `www.mysite.com` to visit my website but only the index page. Meaning that I can't visit all of sub pages, such as `www.mysite.com/page1.html`.

Here is my code:

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/(.*js$)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static/'}),
            (r"/(.*css$)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static/'}),
            (r"/(.*xml$)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static/'}),
            (r"/(.*jpg$)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static/'}),
            (r"/(.*png$)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static/'}),
            (r"/(.*ico$)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static/'}),

            (r"/(.*country\.html$)", PageHandler),
            (r"/(.*city\.html$)", PageHandler),
            (r"/(.*look\.html$)", PageHandler),

            (r"/(index)", SearchHandler),
            (r"/$", IndexHandler),
        ]
        settings = dict(
            #template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "beejeen/"),
            #static_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "beejeen/"),
        )
        super(Application, self).__init__(handlers, **settings)
```

I think I should do some configuration for the tornado but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

In fact it is because I use IP address in the backend code and the frontend code.

So there exists a cross-domain problem.

I replace all of IP with the domain name and it works. Here is an example:
backend:
replace `self.write("http://a.a.a.a/something.html")` with `self.write("http://www.example.com/something.html")`

frontend(ajax):
replace `url:'http://a.a.a.a' + '/index?key=' + request,` with `url:'http://www.example.com' + '/index?key=' + request,`